# Local Name Email Validator (regex)

Tags: regex, validation, email

I'm trying to validate the local name portion of an email address.   The domain name gets pre-populate so I don't have to worry about that part.   Is there a regex expression that I can use to do this?

Comment: You need to validate everything before the `@`? What should be valid/invalid? Emailaddress syntactically correct? Or maybe containing more than x characters? Or having `imaguy` in the pre-`@`part?

Comment: What do you mean by `validate the local name`?

Comment: Hi, by local name I mean validate everything before the @ sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many answers about this regex. Anyways the following regex might help you

1) Validates whole email id (Ex : firstname.12@gmail.com)

```
/^[a-z.]+[a-z0-9._%+-]*@[a-z]+[a-z0-9.-]*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/
```

2) Validates everything except email domain (Ex: firstname.12@)

```
/^[a-z.]+[a-z0-9._%+-]*@$/
```

3) Validates everything except '@< domain name >' (Ex: firstname.12)

```
/^[a-z.]+[a-z0-9._%+-]*$/
```

Check out the plunker for few other regular expressions also.

http://plnkr.co/edit/00ZdEru4PHQms2fIiUYh?p=preview